# Perpendicular vectors of equal length and orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix $A$ and vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\theta \in (0,\pi)$ and this satisfies

$Ax = \cos\theta x - \sin\theta y$, and $Ay = \sin\theta x + \cos\theta y$

I must now proof that $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular vectors of equal length.

I know this means $|x|^2 = |y|^2$ and $x\cdot y=0$, and I also think I should use the preserved Euclidean inner product. How to continue?

Comment: Let $X$ be the augmented matrix $[x|y]$. It suffices to prove that $P=X^TX$ is a scalar multiple of $I_2$. The given conditions in your question mean that $AX=XQ$, where $Q$ is the $2\times2$ rotation matrix for angle $-\theta$. Since $A$ is real orthogonal, we get $X^TX=Q^T(X^TX)Q$ and in turn $PQ=QP$. You may continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. In formulaic terms, the fact that $A$ preserves the Euclidean i.p. is just the property $$(Ax) \cdot (Ay) = x \cdot y .$$

Comment: But as I said in the question, I need to proof that x and y are perpendicular vectors of equal length. I just stated that I knew that this meant that |x|^2 = |y|^2 and x*y=0, how do I proof these two equations?

Comment: NB that, for example, the quantity $x \cdot y$ occurs in both the hint and in the second equation you must establish.

Comment: So I should show that $Ax \cdot Ay$ (thus $x \cdot y$) and that $Ax \cdot Ax = Ay \cdot Ay$, thus $|x|^2=|y|^2$, do you have any sources for where I can find how to proof this, or can you help me?

Comment: You already have all the ingredients in from of you. All that's left to do is, e.g., write $(Ax) \cdot (Ay)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, which you can do with the two relations in the original problem.

Comment: I do not understand how that would help me proof it. Suppose I knew how to write Ax * Ay in terms of x and y, then how did this proof that x*y=0 ?